# Member ControlPanel Logs?

Tags: control-panel, member

Are there some logs which tell, what the member does in the backend?

Something like: "User: «John Doe» Edited this entry at this and that date".

Just a bit more information than what is written on the member account:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not currently... we've discussed adding a sort of audit or activity trail to Craft itself, but haven't flushed out any details or timeline.

In the meantime, you could probably get 95% there with a custom plugin that listens to the various Craft [events](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/events-reference) you're interested in.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. It would be practical to see what my clients alter on their website. Yes a plugin could maybe do the job. But do you know what is great about craft? I made a whole website without a single plugin. And I'd like to keep it that way. Please don't get into the ee plugin mayhem with craftCMS ;)